# How to read TermainsServices IADsTSUserEx Property from LDAP in C#?

Tags: c#, ldap, c#-2.0, terminal-services, iadstsuserex

I have read the following properties from AD,

```
TerminalServicesProfilePath
TerminalServicesHomeDirectory
TerminalServicesHomeDrive
```

I've tried DirectoryEntry and DirectorySearcher. But they does not include the properties.

I found some example in vbscript and VC to read them.
However I failed to make it working in C#. Am I missing some tricky thing?

EDIT: Am I have to run it on "Windows Server" to make it works? Can it be read from win XP?

Comment: I'm not sure whether you need Windows Server, but that's what I'm using (Server 2003). I don't have XP handy, I'm afraid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't remember exactly, but it's something like this:

```
//user is a DirectoryEntry
IADsTSUserEx adsiUser = (IADsTSUserEx)user.NativeObject;
```

then you can get the TerminalServices properties you want via adsiUser.

From my experience you're better off developing on a Windows Server with access to AD due to the libraries you use. Then you'll probably make the above work, too :)

Comment: I tried also, but I got an System.InvalidCastException : Unable to cast COM object of type 'System.__ComObject' to interface type 'TSUSEREXLib.IADsTSUserEx'.

Comment: Are you sure the TS ADSI extension DLL is registered in the COM system via regsvr32 (a tip I picked up from Joe Kaplan on the net somewhere).

Comment: Thanks, I get it works finally.  I have to run regsvr32 before my app start. (And I forgot to restart my nunit yesterday)

Answer (score 3):

I think you can use the `InvokeGet` method on your `DirectoryEntry`, passing in the name of the property you want to read.

*2008-12-10 11:50 CET — Edited in response to the comment*

If I specify a garbage property name, I get the same COM exception. Are you sure the properties you're trying to retrieve are part of the AD schema?

Just to make sure, the code I'm using is as follows:

```
using (DirectorySearcher searcher = new DirectorySearcher("(cn=Test)"))
{
    SearchResult result = searcher.FindOne();
    if (result != null)
    {
        DirectoryEntry entry = result.GetDirectoryEntry();
        string s = entry.InvokeGet("TerminalServicesHomeDrive") as string;
        MessageBox.Show(s ?? "null");
    }
}
```

Comment: I had tried it, and it was failed.
System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException : Unknown name. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80020006 (DISP_E_UNKNOWNNAME))

Comment: For others having the 'unknown name' exception--this is because the terminal server extensions aren't installed.  Easy was to do it is [install](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=7887) the Remote Server Administration Tools (RSAT) and activate them in windows features OR if you've got the appropriate DLL you can run "regsvr32 tsuserex.dll" as mentioned by others.

Comment: This works fine for me. You need to check whether the tsuserex.dll you need (x86 or x64) is in the right system folder (c:\windows\system32 or c:\windows\syswow64) then run resvr32 from the system folders. You can copy from another machine if you don't have the dlls, they should work.

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

```
            DirectoryEntry user = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://" + sLDAP_SERVER + "/cn=" + SAMAccount + "," + sLdapFullPath, sUser, sPwd);

            //ActiveDs.IADsUser iADsUser = (ActiveDs.IADsUser)user.NativeObject;
            ActiveDs.IADsUser cont = null;

            cont = user.NativeObject as ActiveDs.IADsUser;

            TSUSEREXLib.IADsTSUserEx m_TsUser = (TSUSEREXLib.IADsTSUserEx)cont;
            int m_TSLogonDisabled = 0;

            m_TsUser.AllowLogon = m_TSLogonDisabled;
```

Comment: Curios, how does the change of interface handle a failure in this example. is m_TsUser set to null, or is an exception raised?