# C# Active Directory - Tab Remote Desktop Services Profile - Get and Set property Deny Access

Tags: c#, active-directory, remote-desktop

I'm looking for a way to assign the last checkbox that denies access to the Remote Desktop Session Host (as in the attached image). For the textboxes there are no problems, I found the properties.
But for that checkbox? What should I set?

`user.Properties["terminalServicesHomeDrive"].Value     = "ExampleDrive";`
`user.Properties["terminalServicesHomeDirectory"].Value = "ExamplePath";`

[image: Active Directory Tab RDP]

Comment: I have no experience there, but from what I found just now, you can add both ActiveDS and tsuserex.dll as a reference to your project and use the native Windows [`IADsTSUserEx`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/tsuserex/nn-tsuserex-iadstsuserex) interface to do it like this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1538838/1202807

Comment: I tried checking that box and looking for any attributes that changed, and I didn't see any change. So it must be doing something else.

Comment: Any other heroes? :(